# Registered Server window does not show Database Engine or Local Server Groups

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

I am running SQL Server Management Studio 2012 on a Windows 7 machine. After a failed attempt to import my registred servers from SSMS 2008, the icons for Database Engine and Local Server Groups are not displayed in the Registered Servers window: the Registred Servers window is empty.

[image]

As such I cannot register a server from the SSMS GUI, by right clicking the Local Server Groups.

How can I restore the Database Engine and Local Server Groups items?

Comment: Can you still add reporting analysis and integration services ? or are they also gone ?

Comment: If I click these items, nothing happens: no items are displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the folder %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Shell you should find a file named RegSrvr.xml. That's the file where Management Studio stores local registered servers. If the file is missing or corrupt, SSMS won't display anything.

In this case, you can create a new file and paste this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<model xmlns="http://schemas.serviceml.org/smlif/2007/02">
  <identity>
    <name>urn:uuid:96fe1236-abf6-4a57-b54d-e9baab394fd1</name>
    <baseURI>http://documentcollection/</baseURI>
  </identity>
  <xs:bufferSchema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <definitions xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08">
      <document>
        <docinfo>
          <aliases>
            <alias>/system/schema/RegisteredServers</alias>
          </aliases>
          <sfc:version DomainVersion="1" />
        </docinfo>
        <data>
          <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08" xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08" xmlns:sml="http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
            <xs:element name="RegisteredServersStore">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:any namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08" processContents="skip" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="ServerGroup">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:any namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08" processContents="skip" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <RegisteredServers:bufferData xmlns:RegisteredServers="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08">
              <instances xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08">
                <document>
                  <docinfo>
                    <aliases>
                      <alias>/RegisteredServersStore</alias>
                    </aliases>
                    <sfc:version DomainVersion="1" />
                  </docinfo>
                  <data>
                    <RegisteredServers:RegisteredServersStore xmlns:RegisteredServers="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08" xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08" xmlns:sml="http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                      <RegisteredServers:ServerGroups>
                        <sfc:Collection>
                          <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                            <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/AnalysisServicesServerGroup</sml:Uri>
                          </sfc:Reference>
                          <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                            <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/CentralManagementServerGroup</sml:Uri>
                          </sfc:Reference>
                          <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                            <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/DatabaseEngineServerGroup</sml:Uri>
                          </sfc:Reference>
                          <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                            <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/IntegrationServicesServerGroup</sml:Uri>
                          </sfc:Reference>
                          <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                            <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/ReportingServicesServerGroup</sml:Uri>
                          </sfc:Reference>
                          <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                            <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/SqlServerCompactEditionServerGroup</sml:Uri>
                          </sfc:Reference>
                        </sfc:Collection>
                      </RegisteredServers:ServerGroups>
                    </RegisteredServers:RegisteredServersStore>
                  </data>
                </document>
                <document>
                  <docinfo>
                    <aliases>
                      <alias>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/AnalysisServicesServerGroup</alias>
                    </aliases>
                    <sfc:version DomainVersion="1" />
                  </docinfo>
                  <data>
                    <RegisteredServers:ServerGroup xmlns:RegisteredServers="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08" xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08" xmlns:sml="http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                      <RegisteredServers:Parent>
                        <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                          <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore</sml:Uri>
                        </sfc:Reference>
                      </RegisteredServers:Parent>
                      <RegisteredServers:Name type="string">AnalysisServicesServerGroup</RegisteredServers:Name>
                      <RegisteredServers:ServerType type="ServerType">AnalysisServices</RegisteredServers:ServerType>
                    </RegisteredServers:ServerGroup>
                  </data>
                </document>
                <document>
                  <docinfo>
                    <aliases>
                      <alias>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/CentralManagementServerGroup</alias>
                    </aliases>
                    <sfc:version DomainVersion="1" />
                  </docinfo>
                  <data>
                    <RegisteredServers:ServerGroup xmlns:RegisteredServers="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08" xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08" xmlns:sml="http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                      <RegisteredServers:Parent>
                        <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                          <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore</sml:Uri>
                        </sfc:Reference>
                      </RegisteredServers:Parent>
                      <RegisteredServers:Name type="string">CentralManagementServerGroup</RegisteredServers:Name>
                      <RegisteredServers:ServerType type="ServerType">DatabaseEngine</RegisteredServers:ServerType>
                    </RegisteredServers:ServerGroup>
                  </data>
                </document>
                <document>
                  <docinfo>
                    <aliases>
                      <alias>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/DatabaseEngineServerGroup</alias>
                    </aliases>
                    <sfc:version DomainVersion="1" />
                  </docinfo>
                  <data>
                    <RegisteredServers:ServerGroup xmlns:RegisteredServers="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08" xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08" xmlns:sml="http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                      <RegisteredServers:Parent>
                        <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                          <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore</sml:Uri>
                        </sfc:Reference>
                      </RegisteredServers:Parent>
                      <RegisteredServers:Name type="string">DatabaseEngineServerGroup</RegisteredServers:Name>
                      <RegisteredServers:ServerType type="ServerType">DatabaseEngine</RegisteredServers:ServerType>
                    </RegisteredServers:ServerGroup>
                  </data>
                </document>
                <document>
                  <docinfo>
                    <aliases>
                      <alias>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/IntegrationServicesServerGroup</alias>
                    </aliases>
                    <sfc:version DomainVersion="1" />
                  </docinfo>
                  <data>
                    <RegisteredServers:ServerGroup xmlns:RegisteredServers="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08" xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08" xmlns:sml="http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                      <RegisteredServers:Parent>
                        <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                          <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore</sml:Uri>
                        </sfc:Reference>
                      </RegisteredServers:Parent>
                      <RegisteredServers:Name type="string">IntegrationServicesServerGroup</RegisteredServers:Name>
                      <RegisteredServers:ServerType type="ServerType">IntegrationServices</RegisteredServers:ServerType>
                    </RegisteredServers:ServerGroup>
                  </data>
                </document>
                <document>
                  <docinfo>
                    <aliases>
                      <alias>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/ReportingServicesServerGroup</alias>
                    </aliases>
                    <sfc:version DomainVersion="1" />
                  </docinfo>
                  <data>
                    <RegisteredServers:ServerGroup xmlns:RegisteredServers="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08" xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08" xmlns:sml="http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                      <RegisteredServers:Parent>
                        <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                          <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore</sml:Uri>
                        </sfc:Reference>
                      </RegisteredServers:Parent>
                      <RegisteredServers:Name type="string">ReportingServicesServerGroup</RegisteredServers:Name>
                      <RegisteredServers:ServerType type="ServerType">ReportingServices</RegisteredServers:ServerType>
                    </RegisteredServers:ServerGroup>
                  </data>
                </document>
                <document>
                  <docinfo>
                    <aliases>
                      <alias>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/SqlServerCompactEditionServerGroup</alias>
                    </aliases>
                    <sfc:version DomainVersion="1" />
                  </docinfo>
                  <data>
                    <RegisteredServers:ServerGroup xmlns:RegisteredServers="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08" xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08" xmlns:sml="http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                      <RegisteredServers:Parent>
                        <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                          <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore</sml:Uri>
                        </sfc:Reference>
                      </RegisteredServers:Parent>
                      <RegisteredServers:Name type="string">SqlServerCompactEditionServerGroup</RegisteredServers:Name>
                      <RegisteredServers:ServerType type="ServerType">SqlServerCompactEdition</RegisteredServers:ServerType>
                    </RegisteredServers:ServerGroup>
                  </data>
                </document>
              </instances>
            </RegisteredServers:bufferData>
          </xs:schema>
        </data>
      </document>
    </definitions>
  </xs:bufferSchema>
</model>
```

This is what an empty registered servers file looks like in SSMS 2012. It should bring your SSMS back to normal.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem! Probably due to the failed import of Registred Servers from SSMS 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the file from here:

```
C:\Users\peter\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Shell
```

and then restarted Studio.

Comment: "I just deleted the file…" – what file?

Comment: File name is RegSrvr.xml